# Copy data from smaller AudioBuffers into a bigger Float32Array

Tags: javascript, fft, web-audio-api, arraybuffer

**I want to analyze the frequencies coming from the microphone input with a resolution of <1Hz in browser.**

**The normal Web Audio AnalyzerNode has a maximum** FFT_SIZE of 32768. This results in a **resolution of ~1.4Hz** for normal samplerates (48kHz).

Now I want to use jsfft or something similar to do the frequency transform. I want to collect 65536 audio samples as this fft size should reach a resolution of ~0.7Hz. (Time resolution is not that important)

**Unfortunately the ScriptProcessorNode also only has a maximum bufferSize of 16384** I want to combine 4 of its buffers to one Float32Array.
I thought that there will be someting like

```
copyChannelData(array, offset, length)
```

but there is only

```
getChannelData(array)
```

So if I understand right I would have to copy all the data in my bigger array before I can do the fft.

Just to be sure I don't miss anything...**Is there a way to retrieve the data directly into my bigger array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will need to copy the data.  This method is pretty inefficient anyway (ScriptProcessor, I mean) - the copy is not the worst of your worries, since you are fundamentally going to need to copy that data.

Comment: Thank you, I accepted. Feel free to add a more efficient way to reach a better resolution if you know some! For inspiration, [here](https://amcoustics.com/tools/amalyzer) is a first version.